# How can I get pivot_table to apply a function over combinations of values?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a pandas dataframe, and I want to get the averages of the values in one column for each combination of the values in two others.

That is, if I had a dataframe like this:

```
 Temperature   Apple      Banana
 50            MacIntosh  Gran Michel
 28            Jazz       Cavendish
 4             MacIntosh  Canvenish
 100           MacIntosh  Gran Michel
```

I would want a summary like this:

```
 MacIntosh Gran Michel 75
 Jazz      Cavendish   28
 MacIntosh Cavendish   4
```

Comment: Isn't this just `df.groupby(['Apple','Banana'])['Temperature'].mean()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df.groupby(['Apple', 'Banana'], as_index=False).mean()
       Apple       Banana  Temperature
0       Jazz    Cavendish           28
1  MacIntosh    Cavendish            4
2  MacIntosh  Gran Michel           75
```

Or if you want a new index:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Apple', 'Banana']).mean()
                       Temperature
Apple     Banana                  
Jazz      Cavendish             28
MacIntosh Cavendish              4
          Gran Michel           75
```